# Guess the input of a function?

Tags: haskell

I have this body of a function which is

```
x = \y -> [(:), y]
```

I guessed that the type would be

```
x :: (a -> [a] -> [a]) -> [a -> [a] -> [a]]
```

because the function takes an input `y` and produces a `[(:), y]` where `y` equals `y` and then we have function `(:)` again which expects an element of type `a` and a list `[]` to do the prepend.

But I am unable to guess what input should be given to make it work?

I tried `x 2 [3]`
or `x 2 []`
or `x 2 [[3]]`

Thanks

Comment: `x` only has one argument, `y`. Why are you trying to call it with two arguments?

Comment: @melpomene I tried calling it with one argument as well. It didn't work out.. I tried `x 2` and `x [2]` and so on ...

Comment: `(a -> [a] -> [a])` is the type of a function. None of `2` or `[2]` are functions.

Comment: @melpomene I also tried a function like (:) which takes an element of type `a` and prepends it to the following list `[]` like this:

`x (2:[1,2])` or `x (2:[])` but neither worked

Comment: `(2:[1,2])` is not a function but a list (same as `[2,1,2]`). `(2:[])` is not a function but a list (same as `[2]`).

Comment: @melpomene I am out of luck here, do you suggest any function which could work in this case?

Comment: `x` places its argument in a list together with `(:)`. All elements of a list must have the same type. Therefore the argument must have the same type as `(:)`. The easiest way to do that is to use `(:)` again: `x (:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As was said [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52340277/guess-the-input-of-a-function#comment91627833_52340277) by [melpomene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1848654/melpomene), the easiest way to have something of the same type as `(:)` is to use `(:)` itself:

```
> :t x (:)
x (:) :: [a -> [a] -> [a]]
```

What else could we use? Let's write out `(:)` in full:

```
f x xs = (:) x xs = x : xs
```

This suggest some other possibilities:

```
twice x xs = x : x : xs

ntimes n x xs | n <= 0 = xs
              | otherwise = x : ntimes (n-1) x xs

mapping f x xs = f x : xs

filtering p x xs | p x = x : xs
                 | otherwise = xs
```

etc.:

```
> :t x twice
x twice :: [a -> [a] -> [a]]

> :t x (ntimes 33)
x (ntimes 33) :: [a -> [a] -> [a]]

> :t x (mapping sqrt)
x (mapping sqrt) :: Floating a => [a -> [a] -> [a]]

> :t x (filtering even)
x (filtering even) :: Integral a => [a -> [a] -> [a]]
```

The last two are interesting. Though their types are "narrower" in a sense than an unconstrained `(:)`, they are nevertheless allowed to unify with it:

```
> :t [(:), mapping sqrt]
[(:), mapping sqrt] :: Floating a => [a -> [a] -> [a]]

> :t (:)
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

---

*(edit:)* As pointed out in the comments by melpomene, there's even `take` that can be used there as well:

```
> :t x take
x take :: [Int -> [Int] -> [Int]]
```

so the type of `(:)` is allowed to get even more specialized with this one.

This tells us that `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]` is a fully polymorphic type, so we shouldn't be thinking about `(:)` as one "thing", but rather as one "definition", capable of adjusting and fitting in in multiple situations, or uses. Indeed `(:) (5 :: Int)` has the more specialized type

```
> :t (:) (5 :: Int)
(:) (5 :: Int) :: [Int] -> [Int]
```

just as it ought to have. Here the type of `(:)` was specialized by an argument it is applied to. In `x`, this is done by putting `(:)` into the same list with some other function.

Comment: How about `x take`?

Comment: there's also `intersperse`... (Hoogle says). I guess this means `(:)` is treated as fully polymorphic, huh. so we can't think about it as "one thing" but rather as "one definition". I always trip on this one.

Comment: Thanks a bunch @WillNess and @melpomene, I get the concept but even now when I make a query like `x (twice 2 [2])` it gives me an error:
`<interactive>:10:4: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘a -> [a] -> [a]’
                  with actual type ‘[Integer]’
    • Possible cause: ‘twice’ is applied to too many arguments
      In the first argument of ‘x’, namely ‘(twice 2 [2])’
      In the expression: x (twice 2 [2])
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = x (twice 2 [2])
    • Relevant bindings include
        it :: [a -> [a] -> [a]] (bound at <interactive>:10:1)`

Comment: @Moorani Because yet again you're trying to pass a list to `x`. `x` does not take a list (`actual type ‘[Integer]’`), it takes a function (`expected type ‘a -> [a] -> [a]’`).

Comment: @Moorani as we saw in the answer, `x twice == [(:), twice] :: [a -> [a] -> [a]]` (read `::` as "has the type"). this means that `((x twice) !! 0) == (:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]` and `((x twice) !! 1) == twice :: a -> [a] -> [a]`. this means we can call `map (\f -> f 2 [3]) (x twice)`. Try it. What's the result? What's its type? Also, try `map (\f -> f 2 [1..3]) (x take)`. Is the result's type the same, or different?